# Do banks do a credit check when buying a CD?

Tags: united-states, certificate-of-deposit

I had my credit frozen about six month ago when one of the credit bureaus had a data breach (I forget which one it was).  Will I need to unfreeze it before I can buy a CD with a bank, or do banks not do a credit check for this? I'm interested in buying a CD with a bank that I currently do not have an account with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. When you are getting a loan the bank is extending you credit, and they will want to check on your credit worthiness. When you buy a CD you are extending the bank credit! As a creditor you might want to spend some time doing a credit check on the bank, but since most of us retail depositors have neither the resources or the education to evaluate the soundness of a bank, you will probably just rely on the FDIC insurance on your deposit.

They will want picture ID of some sort and your taxpayer id number, but they won't run a credit check.